# Getting one class to interact with another completely separate class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have a base class name Bot; Bot starts up a connection to IRC through another class named IRC (d'oh).

The IRC class contains all the functions necessary to interact with the IRC server (*join*, *part*, *say* and *quit*, just to name a few).

An attribute of Bot named `irc` contains the instance of the IRC class that the bot has started.

Another class named Command serves as a base class for all the commands users on an IRC server can use. Command actually has an argument to it that is supposed to be for a bot instance, although I don't know how I could get the bot instance in there because all commands inherit from the Command class, and I can't be arsed to add super() to every `__init__`.

How can I get the functions in the IRC class to be used by the commands without starting up a new IRC connection every time one connection runs a command (Oh yes, this just happened to me!)?

Comment: Couldn't you use a loop? Or am I misunderstanding you

Comment: Command own an instance of a Bot is backwards, otherwise the class names are. -- If your `Bot` contains an instance of `IRC`, then it should maintain a connection, and not require a new one.

Comment: Are you asking how to access the IRC class from another class?

Comment: @foriinrangeawesome Yes.

Comment: But can't you use dot notation within the Bot class to edit it? eg. `firstIRC.functionName()`, where firstIRC is one instance of the IRC class? Maybe you should try learning more about Objects, Methods, and Instances so you understand what an object is capable of. The documentation for Classes is at this website: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a function in one class from a different one without any other interaction, all you need is a variable that holds the instance of the class who's method you want to run. It is not any different to run a method inside a class as it is outside a class (unless the class is running one of its own methods)

```
class.method()
```

should work fine to run the method